# Kubernetes Ingress path route to different services in different namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

currently I'm trying the following setup:

I have:

- one cluster
- one Ingress Controller
- one url (myapp.onazure.com)
- two namespaces for two applications default and default-test
- two deployments, ingress objects, services for the namespaces

I can easily reach my app from the default namespace with path based routing '/' as a prefix rule
Now i have tried to configure the second namespace and following rule: /testing to hit another service

Unfortunately i get an HTTP404 when i try to hit the following URL myapp.onazure.com/testing/openapi.json

What did I miss?

**Working Ingress 1**

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: liveapi-ingress-object
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public-nginx
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myapp-region1.onazure.com
        - myapp-region2.onazure.com
      secretName: ingress-tls-csi
  rules:
    - host: - myapp-region1.onazure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: liveapi-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
    - host: myapp-region2.onazure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: liveapi-svc
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

**Not working Ingress 2**

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: liveapi-ingress-object-testing
  namespace: default-testing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public-nginx
    #nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /testing
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myapp-region1.onazure.com
        - myapp-region2.onazure.com
      secretName: ingress-tls-csi-testing
  rules:
    - host: myapp-region1.onazure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /testing
            #pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: liveapi-svc-testing
                port:
                  number: 8080
    - host: myapp-region2.onazure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /testing
            #pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: liveapi-svc-testing
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Maybe I am missing a rewrite target to simply '/' in the testing namespace ingress?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but ingress configuration and networking, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I figured out the missing part. I had to add the following statement to the not working ingress object:

```
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
```

Please see the complete ingress object:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: liveapi-ingress-object
  namespace: default-testing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: public-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myapp.onazure.com
      secretName: ingress-tls-csi-testing
  rules:
    - host: myapp.onazure.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /testing/(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: liveapi-svc-testing
                port:
                  number: 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use full DNS name of a service,

```bash
$SERVICE.$NAMESPACE.svc.cluster.local
```

But you need to make sure your ignress controller has acccess to the desired namespace.